# Trouble getting index of class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few hidden modals on a page that I want to control with a single block of javascript code.

I'm trying to test to see if I'm getting the correct close button with class `close`, but my `console.log` is currently printing `-1`.

**HTML**

```
<span class="open">Button A</span>
<span class="open">Button B</span>

<!--modal-->
<div class="modal">

    <!--modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!--close button-->
        <span class="close">&times;</span>

        <!--content A-->

   </div>
</div>

<!--modal-->
<div class="modal">

    <!--modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!--close button-->
        <span class="close">&times;</span>

        <!--content B-->

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    //when a class '.open' is clicked
    $('.open').click(function(){

        //store the index of the clicked span in a variable
        var indexer = $('.open').index(this);

        //test output - working
        console.log("open. " + indexer);

        //store all classes '.close' in a variable
        var close = $('.close');

        //store '.close' with same index as clicked button
        var closeindex = $('.close').index(indexer);

        console.log(closeindex);

    });

});
```

I'm trying to walk through this click function and assign each class with the correct index to a variable, and I'm using `console.log` to print the indexes to the console.

With `console.log(closeindex)`, I'm trying to get the index of the close button that has a matching index of span `.open` that was clicked, but currently it's returning `-1`.

I want to eventually do something like:

```
close.click = function() {
    $('.modal').index(indexer).style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: FYI: `.style.display = "none";` == `.hide();`

Comment: indexer would be a number, not an element.  So it wouldn't find that as being one of the open elements, thus the -1 for not found.

Comment: @Taplar Yeah, I can see that this is unnecessary, but for the sake of visually seeing that I'm referencing the correct `.close`, I wanted to `console.log` its index. I don't trust my javascript skills enough

Comment: Personally, rather than relying on indexes, I would highly suggest using `data` attributes to control which modal each `open` button refers to.

Comment: You should use `.eq` instead of the `.index`. The removed answer was correct.

Comment: I've never used `eq` or `data`, will definitely look into these. Thanks

Comment: @Taplar For getting the index, yes. But for _selecting_ the corresponding `.close` element, no.

Comment: I guess I can just reference child element `.close` of `this`

Comment: It won't work unless it's a direct child?

Comment: Wait, lol, I think i completely ignored the fact that somewhere the code started using '.close', ~_~  Gotta update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to open and close modal dialogs based on the buttons, I'd like to suggest an alternative method to indexes. With indexes, any refactoring/reordering of your elements is liable to throwing your code off entirely.

Consider using `data` attributes to keep track of what modal each `open` button is referring to. That way, no matter where your button/modals are, they are permanently linked.

If you give each modal an ID, and then add that ID to a `data` attribute on your open button...

```
<span class="open" data-modal="modal1">Open Modal 1</span>
<div class="modal" id="modal1"></div>
```

...then you can easily relate open buttons to their proper modals.

The `close` buttons can simply say "Close my parent modal" when clicked. We can do this using [`.closest( selector )`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) which traverses *upwards* in the DOM to find the first matching ancestor.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
$(".open").on("click", function() {
  $(".modal").hide();                  //Hide all open modals
  var modalId = $(this).data("modal"); //Get the Modal ID from the data-modal attribute
  var $modal = $("#" + modalId);       //Select the modal with that ID
  $modal.show();                       //Show it
});

$(".close").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".modal").hide();    //Close the closest modal (ancestry-wise)
});
```

```css
div.modal {
  display: none;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="open" data-modal="modal1">Button A</span>
<span class="open" data-modal="modal2">Button B</span>

<!--modal-->
<div class="modal" id="modal1">

  <!--modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    I'm modal 1!
    <!--close button-->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!--content A-->

  </div>
</div>

<!--modal-->
<div class="modal" id="modal2">

  <!--modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">

    I'm modal 2!

    <!--close button-->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!--content B-->

  </div>
</div>


<!-- -->
```

Comment: The amount of time I've spent trying to figure this out versus how simple this answer is drives me crazy. Thanks

Comment: `data` is just the proper prefix for a custom attribute. For example, you could do `<span data-whatever="hello world"></span>` and doing `$("span").data("whatever")` would output `"hello world"`.

Comment: `var modalId = $(this).data("modal");` should there be a dot in "modal"?

Comment: Nope. The string inside `data()` just refers to the data attribute's name. If it was `data-coffeebot`, then you'd access it by doing `$(this).data("coffeebot");`

Answer (score 2):

```
var closeindex = $('.close').eq(indexer);
```

Ok, so if you have a relationship between open and close such that the 3rd open related to the 3rd close, then you can get the related close by using the eq() method as above.

eq() will get you the element at that index, keeping it as a jQuery object.